# Calculating possible number of configuration

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I am wondering how did they get the $19200$ possible configurations? Like, $5^6 = 15625$, where $6$ is the number of hyper-parameters:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number is:

$$5 \times 5 \times 6 \times 4 \times 4 \times 8$$

which is equal to $19200$. Here, we just count the number of possible values for each parameter.